# Form doesn't get submitted

Tags: php, symfony

I have started to study Symfony2 since I will probably need in my work.

routing.yml:

```
account_register:
    path: /register
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Register:index}
```

RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $register = new User();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($register)
            ->add('email', 'email', array('required' => false))
            ->add('password', 'password', array('required' => false))
            ->add('alias', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('register', 'submit', array('label' => 'Register'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($register);
            $em->flush();

            exit("Error");
            //return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
        }

        return $this->render('pages/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

regiser.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <br /><br />
<div class = "window">
<form>

            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            {{ form_start(form) }}

            {{ form_errors(form) }}

            <div id=center-text>Email</div>
            <div class="textfield" id=center>    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'textfield', 'size': '22', 'maxlength': '100'}}) }}  </div>

            <br />

            <div id=center-text>Password</div>
            <div class="textfield" id=center>    {{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr': {'class': 'textfield', 'size': '22', 'maxlength': '100'}}) }}  </div>

            <br />

            <div id=center-text>Alias</div>
            <div class="textfield" id=center>   {{ form_widget(form.alias, {'attr': {'class': 'textfield', 'size': '22', 'maxlength': '100'}}) }}</div>

            <br /><br />

            <br />
            <center>
                {{ form_widget(form.register, {'attr': {'class': 'button'}}) }}
            </center>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

When i press the submit button only the url changes from http://localhost/website/web/app_dev.php/register
to
http://localhost/website/web/app_dev.php/register?form%5Bemail%5D=&form%5Bpassword%5D=&form%5Balias%5D=&form%5Bregister%5D=&form%5B_token%5D=hd70y_KjUEY8v51dQjnjU0ZMTJ0BYOihurV6IcIvghY

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the expected form's flow. The form that you are submitting is redirecting to the same page.

- If you don't want your form to be in GET, you can change it for POST :

  ```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($register)
       ->setMethod('POST')
       ->...
  ```

When you are redirected after submitting the form, *$form->handleRequest($request)* binds the request (your data submitted) with the form that is just created. *$form->isValid()* then checks if your data is valid according to your form.

- If you don't see any change after being redirected, you should check if *$form->isValid()* returns *true*.
- If you want to redirect your form to another controller method, you should create another resource and then set the *action* attribute of your form thanks to the *setAction()* method.

To sum up, everything that I just told you [is written and explained on this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html), and you definitely should read it ! :-).

Comment: Added setMethod, the url still changes and isValid returns false

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, the html was my test code and then i added the symfony {{ blocks }} and forgot to remove the old  tags